# How to return the camera position in p5js?

Tags: javascript, camera, p5.js

In P5js we can set the camera position with the command

```
camera([x], [y], [z], [centerX], [centerY], [centerZ], [upX], [upY], [upZ])
```

but how can I return the current camera position after some rotation going on with orbitControl() ?
is there a function like cameraX to return the x coordinate of the current camera position like mouseX for the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make a [`p5.Camera`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Camera) instance via [`createCamera()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCamera), hold to it and read/reuse properties such as x, y, z as needed.

Here's the documentation example with a tweak:

```js
// Creates a camera object and animates it around a box.
let camera;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100, WEBGL);
  background(0);
  camera = createCamera();
  // optionally, call camera() on the instance with the same arguments as the global function
  //camera.camera([x], [y], [z], [centerX], [centerY], [centerZ], [upX], [upY], [upZ])
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if(!mouseIsPressed){
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.setPosition(sin(frameCount / 60) * 200, 0, 100);
  }
  box(20);
  // read cam params
  console.log(camera.eyeX + ',' + camera.eyeY + ',' + camera.eyeZ);
}

function mouseDragged(){
  orbitControl();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Very useful! Do you know if it still works after some camera movements with the orbitControl() ? I mean the orbitControl() function moves the camera variable you made?

Comment: I've updated the example above to include a hint at how you might want to call `camera()` on the instance. Additionally, `orbitControl()`, for this one camera seems to pickup the instance automatically which is very convenient. Notice the `lookAt()` and `setPosition()` calls are now within a condition so they don't clash with `mouseDragged() / orbitControl()`. HTH

Comment: @pantsik after a bit of [digging around](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/7227b9a83b7ad51725f7dd9749e3b1e45f6eff6a/src/webgl/p5.Camera.js#L352) I see the most recently created camera becomes the default global camera, however, if you have multiple cameras you can always use `setCamera()` to point to a different `p5.Camera` instance. If the answer is helpful vote it up and if is the solution to your problem mark it with the green tick mark. Thank you

Comment: Thank you again! This was indeed the solution to my problem. I marked it as such but I can't increase the vote counter because it says I need 15 reputiation points.